# WKWebView ask twice for location permission

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation, location, wkwebview

I have a simple iOS Swift App

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.mycustompage.com")!
webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
```

In Info.plist I allowed all privacy-location permissions.

On https://www.mycustompage.com there is a HTML button which locates the user.

Now I have the problem that my app asks twice for the location permissions. 
Once for the app and once for the WKWebView.

How can I disable the request for the WebView!?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that this is because your webpage is asking for location and safari is basically another app running inside your viewcontroller.  One way to bypass this is to simply not ask for the user location in your webpage.  instead ask for the user location in the app, then inject then location into your webview with javascript using [evaluateJavaScript(_:completionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript).  Obviously you need to wait until you have both the location and for the page to be full loaded before you make the javascript call.

Comment: Hi thanks, for your fast answer. Is there another possibility? maybe to allow the access for this page by defaut?

Comment: I seriously doubt it.  Apple always sides with the user over the developer, so they are always going to let the user know when the webpage is trying to access the location.  For instance if they allowed you to whitelist your VC and you navigate to your website, maybe thats ok, but the user could theoretically navigate to another website that could then use their location without their permission; thats why this is a no go.  The injection really isn't that hard to do, provided you are pointing to your own website and can edit the javascript.

Comment: Google sells your data.  You are there product; they're not in the business of promoting user privacy.

Comment: Hello Josh, I found out that your idea is not possible because I need the request for my desktop Webpage. Maybe it is possible to disable or to deny the access for the webview by default. I know the locationservice is not working in this case but I didn' receive the stupid message.

Comment: You can inject a cookie into your webview. Your JavaScript should check for the cookie. If it’s there you wait for the location injection from the app. If not you request location. That lets you not only distinguish between the app and desktop but even the app and safari mobile.